# I want a suggestion to embed a large number of PDF into a Faiss Vector Store | Llama_Index | PDF reader

Tags: python, pdf, langchain, llama-index, faiss

Actually I am trying to build a chat bot which can answer the questions from a set of pdf's.
I use llama_index for retrival.
The bot is working now without any issues.
But the quality of the answers is not that great :( . I believe that is because I have used my custom logic for creating embeddings (15 lines per chunk).
The flow that I followed to embed is

1. Take a pdf - Create a pdf reader object
2. Extract the text from every page and store it in a string
3. Split that string into an array of string based on "\n"
4. Now I create a chunk of llama_Index Document with each 15 lines in a chunk
5. Parse those Documents into Nodes and the create a Vector store index

The issue that i face with this is - Some documents like FAQ and Tables are not properly embedded. - Mostly Question in a document chunk and answer in another. - Using page.extractText() table data is fully collapsed.

This reduced the answer efficiency of my ChatBot.

I tried some logics which can help me get a separate table content into a separate chunk - This increased a little bit of performance.

But I cannot do this for every pdf that I have because, every pdf has followed some different different ways while creation.

I am expecting a couple of things from the experts,

1. Is there any best way to embed such pdfs into my Faiss Vectore Store? If so can you recommend me a solution.
2. Is there a way to make python understand that this is a table content, this is a sub heading in the pdf and so.

I wish either of these 2 will help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @K J. I tried the latest ChatGPTs answer and nothing gave me a hand:(